# Adding a screenshot feature to Android 2.3

Tags: android, screenshot, android-service, android-source, android-framework

I'm implementing a screenshot feature for Android 2.3 (I know that ICS has a screenshot feature already). I'm using the Android Screenshot Library (ASL for short) project as a base, and I'm modifying it to suit my needs. I can also freely modify Android's source code for it. The goal is to have something like what the Galaxy Note does: you take a screenshot with a key press combo and then an editor shows up which allows you to change the image however you like. You could take a screenshot anywhere: on the main screen, while using apps, etc.

Right now I have 3 working parts: a native binary that captures the screen buffer, a service that talks to the native binary and retrieves the screenshot, and the editor. But I'm not sure how I could join the 3 things together. The native binary can be added to the Android prebuilt part and init.rc can be modified to execute it as root when booting (I still have to do this though). The editor is a simple app that can be included in Android as well. But I still can't figure out what to do with the service.

Ideally I'd like to capture a key press combo (say power button and volume down, or maybe two of the front buttons), which would trigger the service. The service would then call the binary to take a screenshot and launch an intent to open the editor with the screenshot. However, as far as I know a service cannot catch key presses. Besides, the service has to be bound somewhere in order to know when it has to take a screenshot, so I guess that I should modify Android itself to start the service and bind to it at startup, but the documentation regarding Android source code is lacking and I have no clue where to start looking.

Does anyone know what component of Android is in charge of the key presses, and where I should bind my service? Is my approach even possible at all?

Thank you in advance for any possible help.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to interact with the keys (yet), but I did a workaround by detecting when the user shakes the phone, which was pretty simple to implement. If I find out how to do what I want, I'll update my question with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356325/how-to-intercept-a-hard-key-pressed-in-a-service). It suggest using the camera button, which is certainly better than overloading other system buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was very afraid that my question would be buried among the others. My device doesn't have a dedicated camera button, though; it only has the power and volume buttons, and the typical 4 capacitive buttons on the front. However, one of the replies in your link (I've been searching for days and I hadn't seen that question yet!) points to InputMethodService, which I'm gonna take a look at right away. Thanks again!

Comment: But why buttons? Dropcap, if I remember correctly, relies on the G-sensor: you shake the device and it takes the screenshot. You could program other patterns, like double tap on the back or similar. Another possibility is delayed screenshot: You start your screenshooting application, press a button in it and have, say, 5 seconds to return to the application you want to take a screenshot of.

Comment: That's a possibility, but since Android ICS does it by pressing the power button + volume down, I wanted to do it in the same way. However, even if I do it with the G-sensor or whatever, I'm still not sure on how I catch this globally and then access my daemon: A service? If so, where do I put it? I'm not planning to make an app to sell in Google Play; I'm trying to build my own Android image for a particular device with this feature.

Comment: A Service is the right place to do it. You can start it from an Activity or at boot time. Your "deamon" can be a part of the service (running in the same process). Or, if it's a part of a different process, you can send it an Intent.

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try. I suppose that if I want my service to run at boot time and stay running in the background, I need to start it instead of binding it to an activity, is that right? Thank you for all these ideas.

Comment: You'll start it from a BroadcastReceiver which listens to BOOT_COMPLETED. This happens only once per boot, so you won't need a permanent connection (i.e. "binding") to the service. But it's still a good idea to have an Activity from which the user can stop the service when not needed anymore.

Comment: You mean creating an app without any activites; just a service that listens to BOOT_COMPLETED, right? And then, in order to trigger the screen capture, just use intent filters to figure out when the user wants to do take a screenshot (like pressing "back" twice or shaking the phone or whatever), right? I'm sorry if I'm asking too many stupid questions bu I'm a horrible programmer. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I mean you'll need to listen to BOOT_COMPLETED and, when it occurs, start your Service. Like a music player service, it would work in the background and react to, say, shaking the phone. Also, like a music player, you might want to add an Activity so the user can stop your service if not needed anymore. Otherwise it would be draining the battery all day long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12235/discussion-between-igor-f-and-ziritrion)